# Contact form styling problems

Tags: html, css, forms, contacts

I am trying to style a contact form I set up on my website. I took a ready made one (html with css styling and php action) but when I put it in my html, it doesn't link the html with the css. How should I define the divs? Thank you.

```html
<div id="contact"  class="contact">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="divider4"></div>
        <form action="mail.php" method="post" id="vreme">
    
            <div class="column-1">
                YOUR NAME<br/><br/>
                <input name="name" id="name" value="" />
            </div>

    
            <div class="column-2">
                YOUR E-MAIL<br/><br/>
                <input name="email" id="email" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="column-3">  
                MESSAGE<br/><br/>        
                <textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea>
            </div> 

            <div class="button">
                <span><input class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "it doesn't link the html with the css" — Why should it, there is no CSS in the code you supplied.

Comment: "How should I define the divs?" — However you want? We don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Have you included the css reference to your page header? As in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form-style.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be a css file for the given html form in that website. You should connect that form.css file to the form.html post by mentioning the following code in the head section of your html. Check it and see

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="contact"  class="contact">
  <div class="row"><div class="divider4"></div>
  <form action="mail.php" method="post" id="vreme">

    <div class="column-1">
            YOUR NAME<br/><br/>
            <input name="name" id="name" value="" />
            </div>


    <div class="column-2">
            YOUR E-MAIL<br/><br/>
            <input name="email" id="email" value="" />
            </div>

    <div class="column-3">  
            MESSAGE<br/><br/>        
            <textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea>
            </div> 

    <div class="button">
                <span><input class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"></span>
              </div>
</form>
  </div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included the css reference, the rest of my page styling is working, that isn't. The weird part is, I took that from a website I had previously worked on, and it worked there perfectly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Form Style</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css"/> //css/form.css - select your file location
/* OR */
<style type="text/css">
/*Paste your css style code here*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contact"  class="contact">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="divider4"></div>
        <form name="mail" action="mail.php" method="post" id="vreme">

            <div class="column-1">
                YOUR NAME<br/><br/>
                <input name="name" id="name" value="" />
            </div>


            <div class="column-2">
                YOUR E-MAIL<br/><br/>
                <input name="email" id="email" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="column-3">  
                MESSAGE<br/><br/>        
                <textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea>
            </div> 

            <div class="button">
                <span><input class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps...